# How to deploy a cross-site publishing environment to prod

Tags: deployment, publishing

I'm building out a cross-site publishing environment on a dev server. So, it will have the following sites/assets:

1. publishing site (myserver/sites/devpubsite)
2. product Catalog Site (myserver/sites/devauthoringsite)
3. managed metadata term store (used for navigation)

What is the recommended approach for moving all this prod? Prod will be a different farm, and the sites will exist on different URLs. ALso, the publishing sites make use of the search results web parts, which rely on the catalog.